# Rewite slug en una página de wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hola podrían ayudarme con este problema que me está complicando la vida. Verán, supongamos que he creado esta página en wordpress: `https://es.stackoverflow.com/ejemplo-de-pagina/` y a esta le agrego un parámetro `GET['t']` quedando así: `https://es.stackoverflow.com/ejemplo-de-pagina/?t=titulo-de-ejemplo`. Bueno lo que quiero hacer es convertir ese parámetro en un slug y que resulte así: `https://es.stackoverflow.com/ejemplo-de-pagina/titulo-de-ejemplo/`. El código que hice para lograrlo, pero que no resultó es el siguiente:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars', 10, 1);

function my_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 't'; 
    return $vars;
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%t%', '([^&]+)');
    $regex = '^ejemplo-de-pagina/([^/]*)/?';    
    $location = 'index.php?page_id=85&t=$matches[1]';
    add_rewrite_rule($regex, $location, 'top');
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
}
```

Sí pudieran ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esta función:

```
convertParamToDirectory($_GET['t']);

function convertParamToDirectory($url){
  if($url != ''){
    $url = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] . $url;
    header('location:  ' . $url . '');
  }
}
```

Lo que hacemos es obtener el valor $_GET['t'] y en la función lo concatenamos con $_SERVER['HTTPS'] y realizamos un header('location').

Comment: Eso redirecciona y lo que quiero es reescribir el slug

Comment: ¡Saludos Mariscal! Gracias por tu interés en aportar contenido a la comunidad; te recomiendo echarle un ojo al [tour] y a [answer]  para que tengas una idea básica de como funciona el sitio. Actualmente tu respuesta carece de peso para poder entenderla, ¿Qué te parece si la editas y nos cuentas por qué tu respuesta soluciona la pregunta? Saludos y bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español :D

Answer (score 0):

Bueno aquí la respuesta:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%t%', '([^&]+)');
    $regex = '^ejemplo-de-pagina/([^/]*)/?';
    $location = 'index.php?page_id=85&t=$matches[1]';
    add_rewrite_rule($regex, $location, 'top');
}
```

Es importante ir al menú "Ajustes => enlaces permanentes" y reiniciar nuevamente la configuración. Luego para acceder a la variable es simple:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Template Test
*/

var_dump($wp_query->query_vars['t']);
```